# How are music commands handled?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In my keyboard I have some keys to play, pause, play next.... to control the music. I would like to know how this is done under the hood. Is it some sort of API in the operating system that passes the information on to the music player? Is the player reading for pressed keys and reacting to them?

Is there a unified way to control music players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to stay platform independent where I can, however, at some point I will have to strive to Windows.

First it is important that you understand what happens when you press a key; this page from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Keyboard_Input_Model) describes exactly the information I am about to summarize in this section. When you press a key, your keyboard generates a scan-code which uniquely identifies your pressed key. However, these scan-codes are keyboard-dependent and you will as good as never work directly with them. Windows, the OS, will translate the scan-codes to virtual-key-codes. Virtual-key-codes are OS-specific codes which resemble their respective scan-codes; virtual-key-codes are what you will usually, in the lowest level, be working with. I should also note that some virtual-key-codes are usually irrelevant to the programmer - such would be keys like "ctrl" which are used for OS commands.

The API for windows can be found in the above link, too, but as far as I know it is for C++; I do not know about Ruby itself.

Now, to your second question, whether the players reads for pressed keys and reacts to them. I am about to present a common principal that is used with keys, buttons, etc., in software design - the actual implementation of the Media Player is a different question. User inputs, which fully require user interaction, are usually implemented with the Oberserver-Oberservable pattern in object-oriented design; the following [link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) explains this pattern for ruby.

In our case, we would have a KeyboardListener acting as Oberservable; it will 'request' from the OS that it would like to be informed when a key is pressed. As well, let us have a MusicManager which is capable of causing music to be player, paused, etc - it acts as Overserver. When a key is pressed the KeyboardListener instantiates an object containing information about what type of key was pressed and passes it to the MusicManager. This would be what happend under the hood, according to this implementation:

1. Press pause button
2. The OS informs the KeyboardListener that pause button was pressed
3. KeyboardListener creates an event containing what button was pressed and passes it to the MusicManager
4. MusicManager determines the cause of action

So why don't we just skip step 2 and go directly to 3? There are several reasons to do so but I will only provide one - it allows the software to be designed in a platform independent, maintainable way. The only code that has to be adopted will be the KeyboardListeners'; it will only need to alter its code on how it 'requests' the OS to be informed. Thus we will have a WindowsKeyboardListener, LinuxKeyboardListener, etc. Which particular Listener will actually be used is dependent upon the runtime environment.